# Add key-value pair to array only if variable is set

Tags: php

I am adding key-value pairs to my array like so:

```
$array[] =
    [
        "key1" => "value1",
        "key2" => "value2",
        // ...
    ]
```

And I want to add another key `foo`, only if the variable `$bar` is set:

```
$array[] =
    [
        "key1" => "value1",
        "key2" => "value2",
        "foo"  => $bar
        // ...
    ]
```

How to add the `"foo" => $foo` pair only if `$foo` is set?

What I do right now is to add empty (`""`) value to the key `"foo"` if `$bar` is not set, but I want to not add it at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every time I need to fill array based on some condition, I do something like this:

```
$array = [];
$array['key1'] = 'value1';
$array['key2'] = 'value2';
    
if (isset($bar)) {
    $array['foo'] = $bar;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not check before setting, like

if $foo is array

```
if(isset($foo) && !empty($foo)) {
    $array['foo'] = $foo;
}
```

if $foo is string

```
if(isset($foo) && $foo != "") {
    $array['foo'] = $foo;
}
```

Comment: In an `isset && !empty` construct, the `isset` is always redundant.