# Append string to JSON only if a variable is set

Tags: php

I have a json array:
`$json = [];`

Then in a loop I add data to it, and these fields have nested structure:

```
$json[] = [
   "key1" => "value1",
   "key2" => array(
       "key3" => "value3",
       "key4" => "value4",                   
       "foo" => $bar 
    )
];
```

How can I add the key `foo` only if `$bar` is set, otherwise not add it at all?

The following doesn't work:

```
$json[] = [
   "key1" => "value1",
   "key2" => array(
       "key3" => "value3",
       "key4" => "value4",                   
       "foo" => $bar ?? null 
    )
];
```

`$bar` is also an array if that matters

Comment: Store that array under "key2" in a temporary variable and conditionally add "foo" to it.

Comment: Ah, I thought there was some PHP magic to do that inline :D, but I will do it this way then

Comment: @JamesWerben Very unlikely. Move on!

Comment: did you see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118875/a-conditional-element-inside-an-array-construct

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A conditional element inside an array(...) construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118875/a-conditional-element-inside-an-array-construct)

Comment: What happened to your last question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73518840/add-key-value-pair-to-array-only-if-variable-is-set

Comment: @NigelRen I realized I asked it too general and it's not doing what I actually needed, but I can't delete it anymore :/

Comment: @steffen But then I will need to also asign the main data block to a temporary variable no? because of the way I assign it with `$arr[] = [ ... ];`, otherwise how would I know where to assign the temporary variable containing `$foo` to that exact position under `key2`?

Comment: No need for a second temporary variable - see answer. You _could_ get the last element however with `array_key_last()`.

Comment: How is this any different from what you asked earlier, https://stackoverflow.com/q/73518840/1427878 ?

Comment: @CBroe the other one is slightly different. But I marked this one as duplicate instead of the other. Is it possible to mark the other one as the duplicate, and leave this one open? This one is more accurate for what I needed because it's specifically about echoing the data inline regardless of nesting level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example code for conditionally adding `$bar` to `json['key2']['foo']`:

```
// some loop
while (true) {
    $bar = []; // set bar to array or null

    $key2 = [
        "key3" => "value3",
        "key4" => "value4"
    ];

    if (isset($bar)) { // or empty($bar)
        $key2['foo'] = $bar;
    }

    $json[] = [
        "key1" => "value1",
        "key2" => $key2
    ];
}
```